# calling information from different data frames whose results match a character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply a function to convert financial accounts from a number of companies to USD.

The firms relating to each currency can be found below.

```
USDfirms <- c("GOOG", "AMZN", "AAPL", "CSCO", "FB", "HP", "IBM", "0992.HK", 
    "MSFT", "CRM", "TWTR", "WB", "ZTE.CN")
CNYfirms <- c("BABA", "BIDU", "1169.HK", "HMI", "3888.HK", "1357.HK", "NTES", 
        "TCEHY", "1810.HK", "0763.HK")
TWDfirms <- c("2357.TW", "2324.TW", "2356.TW", "2498.TW", "3231.TW")
KRWfirms <- c("003550.KS", "005930.KS")
JPYfirms <- c("5563.T", "7752.T")
EURfirms <- "NOK"
```

So `CNYfirms` correspond to Chinese firms whose financial accounts are in CNY. The `dput()` is a dump of approximately 30 companies finances and can be found [here](http://%20https://files.fm/u/amysx7hu).

EDIT: link 2 here http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=06545415747486823455&t=0654541574748682345555828

Its called `BSISCF`

The `df` - `dput`() is called `BSISCF`.

I also have a currency conversion table:

Which looks like the following;

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  date       cny_usd twd_usd  krw_usd jpy_usd eur_usd
  <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2018-04-01   0.159  0.0344 0.000943 0.00941    1.23
```

Data

```
fx <-structure(list(date = structure(17622, class = "Date"), cny_usd = 0.159228, 
    twd_usd = 0.03442, krw_usd = 0.000943, jpy_usd = 0.009408, 
    eur_usd = 1.232305), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("date", "cny_usd", "twd_usd", 
"krw_usd", "jpy_usd", "eur_usd"))
```

I have the following function and what I am trying to do is take the `symbol`column and use `ifelse` statements. So if the `symbol` column matches with a symbol in `CNYfirms` then in the `exchange.rates` column put the `cny_usd` exchange rate from the `fx` table. Do this for all the symbols. NA values will correspond to USD firms since there is no USD exchange rate in the `fx` table.

```
BSISCF <- BSISCF %>% 
  separate(symbol, into = c("ticker", "country"), 
           sep = "[.]", convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%               # The NA values just correspond to US data
  mutate(exchange.rates = ifelse(symbol == CNYfirms, fx$cny_usd,
                                 ifelse(symbol == TWDfirms, fx$twd_usd,
                                        ifelse(symbol == KRWfirms, fx$krw_usd,
                                               ifelse(symbol == JPYfirms, fx$jpy_usd,
                                                      ifelse(symbol == EURfirms, fx$eur_usd, 0)))))) %>%
  select(exchange.rates, everything())
```

Okay this information is the next steps I will take once the exchange rates have been collected

```
  mutate(exchange.rates = ifelse(is.na(country), 1, exchange.rates)) %>% 
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(fx = .*exchange.rates), .vars = vars(Cash.And.Cash.Equivalents:Change.In.Cash.and.Cash.Equivalents)) %>%
  mutate(adjusted_fx = adjusted*exchange.rates) #All financial statements and the stocks adjusted price converted into USD
```

If there is something I did not explain well, let me know.

Comment: Can you post the `dput` output in text, rather than link to it?

Comment: It is too long for the SO post. I will look for another alternative way to easily upload text files.

Comment: You could also just post a minimal example of the data, that would be enough to replicate it.

Comment: I usually would but with this data its a little more complex and I have had problems before with it. I have uploaded a new direct .txt link here: https://file.io/Rf4Fik

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=06545415747486823455&t=0654541574748682345555828